# How do I tune NTFS for subversion

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, svn, jenkins

I'm building a new buildhost for Jenkins that will run Windows 12 Server and check out relatively large c-projects from SVN and build them.

I our current generation of builders a bottleneck is the subversion checkout which can take something like 75 minutes (compared to 10 minutes on a linux host that is equal network wise and somewhat smaller cpu and disk wise). I would therefore like to optimize the filesystem for the load. I'm willing to change filesystem but Win 2012 only gives the options NTFS and ReFS.

This question: [Bad NTFS performance](https://superuser.com/questions/15192/bad-ntfs-performance) discuses how subversion interacts with NTFS but does not contain solutions.

Comment: Is it using a harddisc, or running an ssd?

Comment: Both Windows and Linux are using spinning rust at the moment.